# In sheets is it possible to convert a duration formatted as a string into the number of minutes?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to convert a duration to a number. I have a cell that lists total hours and total minutes from a Google Meet. I am trying to automatically convert that information to the total number of minutes expressed as a number.

Ex: Cell 1(1 hr 8 min)  to  Cell 2 (68)

The google meet data, with the total hour/ total minutes) will be automatically pasted in from the meet report.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the duration always expressed as `X hr Y min`,

**UPDATED:**

```
= ARRAYFORMULA(
    IFNA(
        IF(LEN(B2:B),
            REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\d+") * 60 + REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\D+(.+)min"),
            ""),
        REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\d+")
    )
)
```

[image]

This part extracts the number before the `hr` and we multiply it by 60

```
REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\d+")*60
```

This part extracts the number between `hr` and `min` and we add it to the above result:

```
REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "\D+(.+)min")
```

To adapt the formula to your situation, please consider the following notes:

- Durations in the example starts from B2
- Total is retrieved in C2:C
- Arrayformula is used: i.e. only one formula is used in C2, and no need to copy the formula down

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and it almost solved my issue. This works if all of the meetings are at least 1 hour long (example: 1hr 15min). However, some of the meetings are less than an hour (example: 47 min) and in these cases, an error is returned.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. I acutally used your original formula to come up with this ```=iferror(IF(LEN($C3),REGEXEXTRACT($C3, "\d+")*60+REGEXEXTRACT($C3, "\D+(.+)min"),""), 
if(REGEXMATCH($C3,"hr"), IF(LEN($C3),REGEXEXTRACT($C3, "\d+")*60,""),IF(LEN($C3),REGEXEXTRACT(C3:C, "\d+")*1,"")))``` which also works. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your original string were in A2, and that no meeting ran more than 9 hr 59 min, you could use this simple approach:

`=TIME(LEFT(A2,1),MID(A2,6,2),0)*24*60`

ADDENDUM (after more information added by poster)

This will cover your newly given scenarios:

`=TIME(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(\d+) hr"),0),REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(\d+) min"),0)*24*60`

Comment: This version has the same issue as above, it only works for durations that are at least an hour long. Also, it returned a time instead of the number of minutes. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Keep in mind that we know only what you provide in the post. In the post, you provided one example, and so my solution was based on that model. Given that you may have raw data that does not match that single example, I adapted the formula (see post ADDENDUM above). As for returning a time instead of number of minutes, that is based on the formatting only. Click the results cell/range and change the format from duration to number (or to custom format 0 if you don't want the decimal portion to show).